# How do recursive calls and printing in postorder work (binary tree)?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, pseudocode

Let's say we have a binary tree with this postorder code (this isn't a code in any specific language it is more like a pseudocode)

```
postorder(node)
{
if(node==null)
return

postorder(left)
postorder(right)
print(node)
}
```

I understand that in first call recursion will keep on going until the left leaf is reached, what then?
How does it backtrack and print other element? doesn't calling `postorder(right)` makes us call `postorder(left)` as well as it comes before it?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that in first call recursion will keep on going until the left leaf is reached, what then? How does it backtrack and print other element?

> If you see the code, the **return** statement is used for this
>   purpose. Once the node becomes null, we simply return to the caller in
>   the function stack

Doesn't calling postorder(right) makes us call postorder(left) as well as it comes before it?

> The idea here is very simple. Take the root. if root's null -> return.
>   Else execute `postorder(left)` Next line to be executed is kept track
>   of in the function stack. This process keeps on going till the stack
>   is empty. Finally the node is printed.